# Some of the websites are displaying in text only

Tags: windows-7, laptop, internet, browser, website

I'm experiencing this problem in my computer for three days. Most of the sites are displaying in the text only in any of the browsers I use: IE, Firefox, Chrome.
The sites I frequently use are: Imdb, facebook, and Flipkart. Yahoo, MSN, and Facebook will actually load, except they take an extremely long time (like back to the dial up days) and they only display an abridged, text only version. There are no colors, backgrounds, and mostly no pictures. It's the same with all three browsers. All the mentioned websites are displaying the images and working fine in my friend's computer. I have also cleared cache and cookies in all the browsers. i have uninstalled and   re installed all the three browsers. I have not added any ad blockers plugin in my computer. I have only one antivirus (Kaspersky). Please help

Comment: Not sure if this will work but try this: Open cmd, type (without quotes) "ipconfig /flushdns" (note the space before the /) and then try going to the sites again.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using CCleaner on the machine. https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download 
It gives you a nice overview of the temporaries and caches in the system (Including dns cache).

Just use the cleaner function or else try with the registry cleaner (Remember a backup!) as well.
It's an easy fix for the novice.

Edit: On second thought it could also just be your internet connection? Maybe reset your router if possible.